# How to protect streaming using Wowza application?

Tags: wowza

I want to stream video only when Wowza allows it. How can I configure this in the Wowza application? Without Wowza's permission to stream the video, the publishing stream should be disabled.

Answer (score 2):

There is a module called [Wowza Wrench here](http://wowzatoolbox.com/user-authentication) which can give you simple authentication and authorization solution for your streaming app.

Answer (score 1):

First, see the Wowza quick start guide here : https://www.wowza.com/docs/quick-start-guides .  If you want to control when and if clients connect successfully, using, for example, your own authentication scheme, you will want to download the Wowza IDE, create a module, and provide the following method:

```
public void onConnect(IClient client, RequestFunction function, AMFDataList params) {
```

If you're also using http streaming to iOS clients, also use:

```
public void onHTTPSessionCreate(IHTTPStreamerSession session) {
```

Or, of course, you could just stop sending the stream to Wowza.

Comment: how do i call this from android mediaplayer?

Comment: If your module is configured correctly, Wowza will call this every time a client connects, whether it be HLS or Flash.

Answer (score 0):

You can try an approach used in this open source package: http://wmsauth.org/ . It's for Windows Media Server but this principle may be used for Wowza as well. The main idea is to modify the link to the media source and thus control the output on a server side.

WMSAuth for Wowza is also planned to be launched as part of https://wmspanel.com/ by the beginning of May. Streams protection will be controlled via the centralized web interface.